# Исключение при подключении к БД

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД PostgreSQL, jar драйвер в библиотеку добавил, код следующий:

```
 public static void connection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Подключение к БД прошло успешно");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Получаю ответ:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://localhost:9000/MyDb
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at Connect.connection(Connect.java:15)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Может кто-то подсказать в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схема URL к бд в вашем случае должна содержать `postgresql`: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/MyDb`

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо